# Laravel array how to save to database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Question is I want to store that array to database to like this and topics can be more or less.

**Database Choice table**

```
|----|---------|----------|------------------|
| id | user_id | topic_id | question_number  |
|----|---------|----------|------------------|
|  1 |   1     |1st array |        21        |
|----|---------|----------|------------------|
|  2 |   1     |2nd array |        5         |
|----|---------|----------|------------------|
|  3 |   1     |3rd array |        3         |
|----|---------|----------|------------------|
..............................................
| 34 |   1     |34  array |        5         |
|----|---------|----------|------------------|
```

**dd**

```
array:3 [▼
"_token" => "HhR1wmjgJUvmnRsoYxcg3yezqzq7ORKqX6dAHzCD"
"time" => "30:01"
"number" => array:34 [▼
1 => "21"
2 => "5"
3 => "3"
4 => "0"
5 => "0"
6 => "0"
........
34 => "5"
]
```

**Controller store function**

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $time = $request->input('time');
    foreach ($request->input('number') as $key => $value) {
        Choice::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'time'  => $time,
            'topic_id' => $key,
        ]);
}}
```

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: No. because i didn't found how to take arrays datas. but I'm still searching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $time = $request->input('time');
    foreach ($request->input('number') as $key => $value) {
        Choice::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'time'  => $time,
            'topic_id' => $key, // or  $key . 'st array';
            'question_number' => $value,
        ]);
    }
}}
```

Comment: what is dd($request->input('number'));

Comment: Of course. i was just waiting 10 minutes. for accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks. You whant save 'topic_id' => 1,  or 'topic_id . '1st array'?;

Comment: No I can handle that. I guess.